# How can I convert a decimal code of a character into a Unicode string in C++?

Tags: c++, string, unicode, decimal

How can I convert a decimal code of a character into a Unicode string in C++?
For example, I give it the integer 241, that is the 'ñ' spanish letter, and I want to convert it to a Unicode string.

Comment: There is no such thing, typically, as a "unicode string". You must specify which *encoding* you want your string in, UTF-8 is the most common.

Comment: except in windows where UTF16LE is the most common

Comment: @unwind: I disagree, "unicode" is commonly understood to be UTF16, where  each character is 16 bits wide.  When the UFT-8 encoding is desired, it is specified explicitly.

Comment: @unwind: How can I specify the encoding?

Comment: @John Knoeller in UTF-16 not every character is 16 bits. What you mean is UCS-2. UTF-16 supports surrogate pairs in order to encode characters outside the BMP.

Comment: @VoidPointer: Good catch, yes I did mean UCS2.  (I just didn't expect to be understood if I said UCS2).

Comment: Sorry, no encoding is needed. ñ' __IS__ U+00F1. Encodings are transformations, e.g. UTF-8 transforms a codepoint value to a byte sequence. That's not needed here.

Comment: Eduardo, which string class (or toolkit, for that matter) are you using?

Comment: @JohnKnoeller: "*"unicode" is commonly understood to be UTF16, where each character is 16 bits wide.*" This is wrong in many ways. Only on Windows does "unicode" commonly mean UTF-16. Unicode means ***Unicode***, which is a specific international standard that *includes* UTF-16. Unicode is UTF-16 like programming is C++. Second, UTF-16 does *not* mean each "character" is 16-bits wide. Surrogate pairs mean that many characters are 32-bits wide. You *cannot* assume that the number of characters is the length of a UTF-16 string.

Answer (score 1):

If your source character set is ISO 8859-1 or 8859-15 (both of which have LATIN SMALL LETTER N WITH TILDE at code point 0xF1 = 241), then the conversion needs to create the correct encoding for Unicode character U+00F1.

Now, we need to know which Unicode encoding scheme you are using.  If you use UTF-8, you will need the result:

```
 \xC3 \xB1
```

If you use UTF-16 BE (big endian), you need:

```
\x00 \xF1
```

If you use UTF-16 LE (little endian), you need:

```
\xF1 \x00
```

If you are using UTF-32, then you need 4 bytes instead of 2.

And if you want a string, you will need to encode the U+0000 (NULL) as a following character.

If you don't know which form you need, you have big problems; to use Unicode, you need to understand something of how the different forms are encoded.  Your library may save you from a lot of the bother of understanding, but ultimately, you need to know at least a [minimum about Unicode](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Answer (score 0):

If the character code is determined at runtime, and you cannot use literals like [explained by Jonathan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2169374/334761), you need to rely on your toolkit. For example, in Qt:

```
QString codepointToString(QString codepointDecimal) {
    int codepoint = codepointDecimal.toInt(); //TODO: check errors
    QChar character(codepoint);
    return QString(character);
}
```